# Limiting rows of table and appending rows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo, html-table

In this code I am getting posts from database in table, table displays posts in three columns, now I want to add some jQuery to limit the number of rows and add a button which on clicking appends few rows to table I am not a professional programmer may be something like `slice` should be used to limit number of rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

<table>
<tr>
<?php do { //horizontal looper?>
<td>
<div>id</div>          
<div>title</div>
<div>body</div>          
<div>date</div>
</td>
<?php
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!isset($nested_List)) {
$nested_List= 1;
}
if (isset($row) && is_array($row) && $nested_List++%3==0) {
echo "</tr><tr>";
}
} while ($row); //end horizontal looper 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: You have to do it manually by sending ajax every time to fetch further records on the bases of last index.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to limit the number of rows ... which rows? The rows you are fetching from the database or the overall  number of rows you can append to your table?

Comment: @Gacci rows fetching from  database

Comment: You accomplish this by using LIMIT param1, param 2. param1 indicates where to start grabbing rows, and param2 indicates how many rows to collect. i.e LIMIT 7, 10 starts looking at rows 7 and collecting if conditions are met. It collects 10 rows if available, else collects as many as available less or equal to 10

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

Create your table (You can also create dynamically)

```
<table id='posts'>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button id='load-more-entries'>Load</button>
```

### JavaScript

Create a variable for keeping track of what result you are on. What the index of the last result you grabbed. 
Grab the elements by id. attach listener to button so when you click you load more results. Take a look at AJAX documentation. It is very simple and short.

```
var index = 0;
var load, table;

load = document.getElementById('load_more_entries'),
table = document.getElementById('posts');



load.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    processAjaxRequest({
        type: 'get',
        url: "posts.php?index="+index,
        success: function(xmlhttp){
            var results = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i){
                var row = table.insertRow();

                var cell = row.insertCell(cell_index);
                //increment index according to how many results you            
                grab so next time you grab the next results
                index++;
            }
        },
        error: function(xmlhttp){
            //Handle error
        }
    });
});

/*
     this function here it is a a wrapped AJAX 
     it will call php file below and run it. It will fetch the results
     form database and return them to you in form of a string. You need
     to parse it JSON.parse() to turn it into an array
*/
function processAjaxRequest(object){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() ||
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            if(xmlhttp.status === 200){
                object.success(xmlhttp);
            }else{
                object.error(xmlhttp);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open(object.type, object.url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type',
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(object.args);
};
```

### PHP

This file is called by processAjaxResquest

```
    $posts = array();
    while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $posts[] = $post;
    }

    echo  json_encode($posts);
?>
```

*NOTE I have not tested the code there maybe a couple of thing I may have left of. However, this should be enough to get you started. I got the same kind of answer when I had this question. Also, note that there is also more things you need to be aware of; like checking the variables inside PHP file are set before you do anything.